# RVM use gemset not creating .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

### Facts

1. I created project1 and ran the following code:

   `rvm use ruby-2.1.0@project-gemset`
2. Then I moved out of the directory and created project2, running the same rvm code.
3. When I run `rvm gemset list` I see that it is using the same gemset as project1.

### Question

Why aren't **.ruby-version** and **.ruby-gemset** being created for **project2**?
I can't see them when I run a `ls -a` on project2's path.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to create the files you need to add flag:

```
rvm use ruby-2.1.0@project-gemset --ruby-version
```

or explicitly create it:

```
rvm use ruby-2.1.0@project-gemset
rvm rvmrc create .ruby-version
```

Comment: Do both (or either) of the solutions above create the .ruby-gemset file as well?

Comment: yes both should create it, if it does not happen open a bug report https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/